# Connecting dual Samsung 24" SR65 monitors in Extended mode to Widows and MacBook Pro

Tags: windows-10, usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi, macbook

Based in the UK. I'm looking for the correct adapter/splitter that can be used for both, MacBook Pro 2017 and Windows HP EliteBook 830 G5 laptops to connect in Extended mode to 2 Samsung 24" SR65 monitors.

**MacBook Pro** has Four Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) ports with support for:
Charging
DisplayPort
Thunderbolt (up to 40 Gbps)
USB 3.1 Gen 2 (up to 10 Gbps)

**Windows HP EliteBook 830 G5** has the following ports:
(1) Thunderbolt (USB Type-C connector),
(2) USB 3.1 Gen 1 (1 charging),
(1) HDMI 1.4b port

Each monitor has:
1 x HDMI,
2 x USB3.0,
2 x USB2.0,

I have tried a few splitters from Amazon (including a Matrix splitter), but none work to Extend the monitors for MacBook, only mirroring the same screen. I've managed to find the ANKER Plug-and-Play Anker USB C to Dual HDMI Adapter and it works well for the Windows laptop to extended onto 2 monitors. Not sure there is a universal hub/splitter that works for both and doesn't cost first class ticket to the Moon...

I have also bought 2 USB3.0 to USB-C cables and expected them to work for Mac via 2 different USB-C (Thunderbolt) ports, but doesn't look like USB3.0 ports can be used for that purpose.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've had enough of buying and returning various devices and cables every few days. Help! SOS ;-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this the product you had working on Windows but not the Mac?
https://www.anker.com/es/products/variant/powerexpand-usbc-to-dual-hdmi-adapter/A83240A1

Here's your problem, from the product description:

> Notes
>
> macOS and iPadOS only support Single-Stream Transport (SST) mode.
>
> Windows supports both Single-Stream Transport (SST) and Multi-Stream
> Transport (MST) mode.

What is the goal here?  Are you looking for one docking station that both computers can use?  Are you expecting both computers on the same desk, at the same time, and flip the displays between the two?  If you are going to switch the displays often then a KVM switch is called for.

The reason one device is not working on both is because the Apple devices do not support DisplayPort MST.  I believe they can support multiple Thunderbolt displays on one port.  I don't know if the HP will support two Thunderbolt displays though.

You didn't list these but if I'm looking at the right spec sheet the displays appear to have VGA, HDMI, and DP inputs.  It would be trivial to keep your dual HDMI adapter for the Windows computer and then get a couple USB-C to DP cables for the Mac.  I assume the displays will auto-switch to whatever port is receiving video so to switch one to the other is to unplug one computer then plug in the other.  Leaving both computers plugged in works too, you will just have to flip the inputs with the display controls.

The Mac would use two ports for two displays but the Windows computer can get away with one port for both displays.  That's just how it's going to have to work, unless you invest in a Thunderbolt dock for the Mac.  Again because Windows uses MST for multiple displays while Apple uses something else.  This has frustrated many people for some time.

Oh, and there's the KVM option.  Like the Thunderbolt dock option this will not be cheap.  I don't know your budget so I don't know where to draw the line on options.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply! Yes, that is the ANKER splitter that I can use for HP (Windows) laptop with no issues, but it's only mirroring from MacBook. I have purchased and tried 2 USB-C to DP cables from Mac, but the monitors don't pick up the signal. I have played with switching the input source into monitors from HDMI to DP, but no luck. Do I need any other hubs/adaptors to get USB-C/DP cables to work with Mac in an extended mode? I found some promising KVM products, but they cost over £200, which is quite steep for me. Thanks a lot! Best

Comment: Also, the monitors do not have VGA inputs, only the following: 1 x HDMI, 2 x USB3.0, 2 x USB2.0 (each monitor). I found this video (copied below) on YouTube and it seems like that solution would work perfectly well for me, but I'm not sure why do I need 'doles' if my USB-C to DP cables can be connected directly between MacBook and the monitors. https://youtu.be/w2e5FoZN5F4

Comment: @Russguyuk  You say you are using DP cables to connect your monitor but also say it has no DP port, that does not make sense.  I don't know what a "doles" is, I can't help you with that.  The video you linked to should have answered your question.  You need only get two of the right cable to connect the MacBook to each monitor.  If all you have is HDMI then get cables that support USB-C/DP to HDMI.  There are USB-C/HDMI (USB-C with the HDMI wiring/protocol) to HDMI but those will not work as Apple computers do not support that video mode natively.

Comment: @Russguyuk  Perhaps you should simply buy the cables and adapters from the Apple Store.  They may cost a few dollars more but Apple will have tested every cable with their computers, so the small premium (if there is one at all, their prices are actually sometimes lower than others) is worth saving your time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for getting back! My bad for missing the crucial point that my monitors **do have** DP ports (1 per monitor). As for 'doles', seems like an autocorrect while typing 'dongles'. So, I bought the USB-C to DP cables, but they don't seem to work with my Mac. Apple store is my next stop as it looks like I'm getting nowhere with current adapters and cables. Should you have any other ideas, please let me know. Greatly appreciate your help!